# gunicorn failed to start worker process while working withDjango app

Tags: django, gunicorn, python-venv

Good Afternoon, I am developing a Django App and trying to develop it using gunicorn and nginx as web server loadbalancer for http. when trying to start gunicorn from within an venv (the app is being developed within a venv )using

../bin/gunicorn biblio_cfv.wsgi: application

I get these errors

```
[2016-10-14 16:37:13 -0400] [22618] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-10-14 16:37:13 -0400] [22618] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (22618)
[2016-10-14 16:37:13 -0400] [22618] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-10-14 16:37:13 -0400] [22621] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22621
[2016-10-14 20:37:22 +0000] [22621] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/eddyraz/proyectos/www/VPS_WEB_DEVEL/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 368, in import_app
    app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I checked the file util.py withon gunicorn code and found nothin wrong

here is the function of the code that gives the error.

```
def import_app(module):
    parts = module.split(":", 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        module, obj = module, "application"
    else:
        module, obj = parts[0], parts[1]

    try:
        __import__(module)
    except ImportError:
        if module.endswith(".py") and os.path.exists(module):
            msg = "Failed to find application, did you mean '%s:%s'?"
            raise ImportError(msg % (module.rsplit(".", 1)[0], obj))
        else:
            raise

    mod = sys.modules[module]

    try:
        app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)

    except NameError:
        raise AppImportError("Failed to find application: %r" % module)

    if app is None:
        raise AppImportError("Failed to find application object: %r" % obj)

    if not callable(app):
        raise AppImportError("Application object must be callable.")
    return app
```

Please could anyone shed any light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which platform are you using for your development environment?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04, nginx 1.10 gunicorn 0.19 Django 1.8.13 postgresql 9.4 all in a venv.

Comment: Edit your file with `vi` and make sure that you do not have any strange characters in front of `app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)`

Comment: I already checked and nothing, it's depressing. I temporarilly moved to using pysolr to search and haystack to rebuild indexes via Django(I know is the least optimal solution , but I am in a hurry). Iĺl keep trying and keep you informed of my findings about it.

Comment: There is another alternative to `gunicorn` if you want to give it a try and it is `uwsgi`

Comment: I have to excuse myself I mixed two problems, the, my previous comment was about anotehr problem I had with haystack, Actually I moved to uwsgi and "almost" everything works great, but is just now nginx is not processing well css.

Comment: You need to update your server config for nginx to serve static files, try to add `location /static/ { alias /path/to/your/static/; }`

Comment: I already did that and all is working like a charm, Thanks so much.

Comment: Also experiencing this error

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but I resolved mine just now.

Just 'pip install gunicorn' in that virtual environment